# Get script on option select with this value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a select box to pull some data that is built into the site. However there are a few modules that run a script , and using the select option , that script is not firing when its selected. Do i have to run the full script within my option function , or can it be called to execute again when its selected.

Here is my script and html. Option Value "MESSAGE12" - needs a script to run when selected.

```
if(unescape(location.href).indexOf("http://football")!=-1||unescape(location.href).indexOf("http://6")!=-1) { 
    var currentServer=baseURLDynamic;
    xmlBaseURL = baseURLDynamic + '/fflnetdynamic' + year + '/';
} else {
    var currentServer=baseURLStatic;
}
function getHomePageModule(thisSelection) {
    if(thisSelection=="")
    document.getElementById("homePageModule").innerHTML = "Your selected module will appear here!";
    else {
    var url = currentServer + "/" + year + "/home/" + league_id + "?MODULE=" + thisSelection.toUpperCase();
    $.get(url, function(data){
    document.getElementById("homePageModule").innerHTML = $(data).find('#pageContent').html();
    });
    }
}    


<select onchange="getHomePageModule(this.value)">
<option value="default">Select A Module</option>
<option value="MESSAGE12" >Get HPM#12</option>
<option value="LIVESCORING" >Link To Live Scoring</option>
<option value="LIVESCORING_SUMMARY" >Live Scoring Summary</option>
</select>

<div id="homePageModule">Your selected module will appear here!</div>
```

Here is a link to my demo select box - http://football29.myfantasyleague.com/2015/home/72758?MODULE=MESSAGE11

And a link to the MESSAGE12 content i'm wanting to fire up in the select box
http://football29.myfantasyleague.com/2015/home/72758?MODULE=MESSAGE12

Any advice appreciated

Comment: Ugh, why the mix between `document.getElementByID` regular javascript and jQuery?  You *have jQuery,* **use it.**

Comment: i had a friend do this , i'm about clueless in javascript , if you can make it better , please share , would be much appreciated

Comment: `$("#homePageModule")` would be the jQuery way of doing `document.getElementById("homePageModule")`.  The [API](http://api.jquery.com) is very easy to understand, there are methods for everything and contain all kinds of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `innerHTML` ([which doesn't evaluate `<scripts>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)), you could try using jQuery's [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

Change:

```
document.getElementById("homePageModule").innerHTML = $(data).find('#pageContent').html();
```

to:

```
$("#homePageModule").append($(data).find('#pageContent').html());
```

(This also replaces the call to `getElementById` with a jQuery selector.)

If that doesn't work, you might need to take a look at the content returned by the call to `$(data).find('#pageContent').html()` and make sure your scripts are there, and/or move the scripts into a function that can be called after the `.append()` finishes.